# header of a text file in RDD

Tags: apache-spark, rdd

I use spark with java and I have a .csv file which contains the elements below:

```
Id,Name,Color,Age
1,Titi,Jaune,5
2,Médor,Noir,10
3,Pitié,Noir,5
```

When I create my pairRDD I want to strip the header so it will look like:

```
(1,Titi,Jaune,5)
(2,Médor,Noir,10)
(3,Pitié,Noir,5)
```

I don't want to use filter() function because it will treat all lines and this is inefficient.

After computing, I would like to save my pairedRDD again as a text file, in this case want to get back the header to the top of file. How can I do this?

One more thing, when i use the following code to create a pairRDD from a javaRDD

```
public Tuple2<Integer, String> call(String x) {
     return new Tuple2(x.split(",")[0], x);
}
```

The tuple in java RDD looks like:
 `(1,Titi,Jaune,5)` after transform it to a pairRDD , it looks like `((1),(1,Titi,Jaune,5))`, e.g the key of the tuple is repeated, why is this happening? I don't want the key to be repeated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**To skip the header:**

You could use `subtract` method to delete the first record of rdd:

```
String headerSTR = "Id,Name,Color,Age";
JavaRDD<String> header = jsc.parallelize(Arrays.asList(headerSTR));
yourRDD = yourRDD.subtract(header);
```

**To avoid the repeated key in Tuple:**

You could easily subtract the id from x:

```
public Tuple2<Integer, String> call(String x) {
    String strs = x.split(",");
    return new Tuple2(strs[0], x.replaceFirst(strs[0]+",", ""));
}
```

it will give you something like: `((1),(Titi,Jaune,5))`

Is that what you seek for?

Bon courage :)

Comment: why i have to use this line ?JavaRDD<String> header = jsc.parallelize(Arrays.asList(headerSTR)); can't i just remove the header direcltly from my RDD

Comment: bcz the method `subtract` of `JavaRDD` requires a `JavaRDD` as parameter, so you should convert it to JavaRDD first

Comment: ok  thank you but one more thing, would you detail for me how it works exactly this line Tuple2(strs[0], x.replaceFirst(strs[0]+",", ""));   please

Comment: well i understood how it generates the key , but the part of value it s little unclear for me

Comment: strs[0] is your first element (id here), and you pick that as the key, so in the second parameter, you don't need the id in the value element, you could simply replace your id with an empty string

Comment: strs[0] is id (e.g. 1), `strs[0]+","` stands for id with comma, you replace it (e.g. "1,") with empty string so what left is just "Titi,Jaune,5"

Comment: it's like you remove "1," from "1,Titi,Jaune,5"

Comment: emm i tried it and it works and i understood it very well, Merci beaucoup

Comment: but what about this question : After computing, I want to save my pairRDD again as a text file, in this case want to get back the header to the top of file. How can I do this?

Comment: you could do with `union`: `finalRDD = header.union(yourRDD);`

Comment: oh ok interesting in fact it s an easy way ,merci beaucoup